# AutoLayout for a left/right aligned view

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass that will work a bit like in Messages app where sometimes it will be left aligned and sometimes right aligned.

When left aligned it will look like this... (in pseudo AFL code).

```
|-[image(==30)]-[label]-(>=standard)-|
```

...and when right aligned it will be...

```
|-(>=standard)-[label]-[image(==30)]-|
```

**First solution**

I was thinking that I could have a couple of methods like this...

```
- (void)setUpLeftAlignedConstraints;
- (void)setUpRightAlignedConstraints;
- (void)removeAlignmentConstraints;
```

So I can do something like...

```
if (self.leftAligned) {
    [self removeAlignmentConstraints];
    [self setUpLeftAlignedConstraints];
} else {
    [self removeAlignmentConstraints];
    [self setUpRightAlignedConstraints];
}
```

But I know that if I use `leading` and `trailing` attributes then this will be automagic based on the writing direction of the current language.

Is it possible to set the direction of the constraints manually?

i.e. tell it if `leading` is the left or right edge?

That way all I need to do is change this setting and the constraints will work for both ways.

Comment: I don't think so. I believe the writing direction comes from the device locale, and isn't something you can flip from within an app. (This is a comment, not an answer, because I'm not sure)

Comment: @jrturton ah I thought that might be the case. Gonna go down my original route then. Thanks

Comment: @jrturton in the end I dropped AutoLayout completely and went back to CGRectMake...

Comment: Disappointing, but understandable

Comment: dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184790/autolayout-badass-way-to-toggle-a-box-left-and-right